# Facebook Login using oauth 2.0 with authorization code on Android

Tags: android, facebook, oauth-2.0, facebook-login, account-kit

I am using Facebook Login SDK to let users sign into my Android app with Facebook. I am also using Facbook's AccountKit SDK to let them login with phone / email.

THe curious thing to note is that Facebook login SDK does not let me retrieve the auth code in the oauth flow, it only directly passes to me the access token, which is inherently less secure to pass around in the client side. This is exemplified by the fact that if I disable client login with oauth in the Facebook Login settings on my app page, I cannot login to my app with Facebook app.

[image]

However, the AccountKit SDK has no such issues.

Does anyone know if there is a way using Facebook Login SDK to only retrieve the auth code when I press "Connect with Facebook" button ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable Client OAuth Login in your Facebook App Settings.

check [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security/#surfacearea)

Comment: I know that. But the point is, passing Access token itself to the client is less secure than the auth code as the grant. Because if somebody is snooping on the client specifically, they might be able to get the access token after breaking into the transport layer security. It defeats the purpose of implementing OAuth 2.0.